# Integrating SQLFire in Maven

Tags: maven, vmware, sqlfire

I'm trying to integrate SQLFire in a Maven project. What I specifically would like to have is the SQLFire thin client.

While searching the web I found the following blog: http://blogs.vmware.com/sqlfire/2012/05/how-to-integrate-sqlfire-into-your-maven-project.html

The problem is that when looking at the repository URL you get:

```
<Error>
 <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
 <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
 <Key>maven/release</Key>
 <RequestId>6AD3E84E43925D03</RequestId>
 <HostId>r/GKK28ZnIkzXycfYARTMxjwTKclJzlgH+zv2yeq3erkcvdwdtZEGIRD3ESF8mF5</HostId>
</Error>
```

What is "NoSuchKey" in this case? Does access to the repository require a key from VMWare ?

Please advise.

Thanks,

Ika.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the blog is correct after all. I found that I had environment issues that was fixed once I consulted with my release engineer.